# hide sheet that not in array

Tags: excel, vba

I made array with the name of sheets that I want to select.
all the other sheets I want to hide.
its need to by dynamic.

list say that my array is
Sheets(Array("Sheets1", "sheet2")).Select
and I have 4 sheets
how I can hide all the others sheet that not in the array ?

Answer (score 3):

### Hide Sheets

- The `Sheets` collection includes worksheets, charts, and whatnot.
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63085324) is a similar solution for **worksheets**.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HideSheets()
    
    ' Do NOT hide:
    Dim Exceptions As Variant: Exceptions = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
    
    Dim sh As Object
    
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            On Error Resume Next ' when trying to hide last visible sheet
                If Not sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
                    sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
                End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next sh
    
End Sub
```